# How to assign App Roles to a user or group with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I work with Azure AD and Microsoft Graph SDK (and some beta API functionalities) instead of Azure AD Graph API, as recommended by Microsoft.

But now, I would like to know if it is possible to assign roles to a user or a group ?

I retrieve groups and users, application roles, but I can't find the way to assign a role to a user/group.

Everybody talks about Azure AD Graph API but not Microsoft Graph :(

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_members

Answer (score 0):

Per https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph this is still not available in Microsoft Graph v1.0, but should be available in /beta, but I don't think it's working properly.  So, if you need this functionality, then for now, you'll need to use Azure AD Graph API. We hope to remedy this at some point, but I don't have an ETA.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Than you Dan for your answer. I will fallback to Azure AD Graph API, especially for this functionality :(

I think there is no other way to do that at this moment.